# How do mobile phones switch 4G/3G/2G?

Tags: electrical-engineering, signal, communication, lte

I would like to know the algorithm of switching between 4g/3g/2g. When will the phone switch from 4G to 3G or from 3G to 2G, when we select for corresponding option in the mobile phone. Is it based on dBm/RSCP etc? I am looking for some technical document. TY